# Вызвано исключение по адресу: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

Tags: c++, c

```
void fillMassL(float **massL, int size)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (i == j) massL[j][i] = 1;
            else massL[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Компилятор показывает ошибку где-то тут, но вообще не могу понять что не так.

```
if (i == j) massL[j][i] = 1;
else massL[j][i] = 0;
```

Cообщение компилятора:
Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6B49826F5 в LR1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF., произошло

Вызов функции:

```
fillMassL(ptr_massL, *ptr_size);
```

Создание ptr_massL:

```
int *ptr_size = new int;
*ptr_size = 5;                                                                      
float **ptr_massL = new float*[*ptr_size];
```

Comment: Текст ошибки, пожалуйста, в студию

Comment: И приведите код создания massL

Comment: Приведенная ошибка - не сообщение компилятора, это ошибка времени выполнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maccив `ptr_massL` создан некорректно. Должны быть 2 этапа:

1. Выделяется память под сам массив указателей на `float`;
2. В цикле выделяется память под каждый его элемент.

   ```
   float **ptr_massL = new float*[*ptr_size];
   for(int i = 0; i < *ptr_size; ++i)
       ptr_massL[i] = new float[*ptr_size];
   ```

Вот тогда все будет ок.

Comment: Забыл докинуть в цикл к другим массивам. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Если это

```
float **ptr_massL = new float*[*ptr_size];
```

и все создание массива, то вы глубоко неправы :) - нужно же еще выделить память для "второго измерения":

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < *ptr_size; ++i)
    ptr_massL[i] = new floaf[*ptr_size];
```

Comment: Спасибо, забыл в цикл, где выделение памяти для других массивов добавить. Пора спать ложится, похоже

Comment: Приятных сновидений :)